# using memory instead of hard drive for converting docx to pdf

Tags: python

I am trying to use *docx2pdf* to convert some .docx files to pdf (and serve them from a django server). The docx files come from a blob-field in my database. So first i save it to the hard drive, then convert it on the hard drive, then send it out. All those hard drive operations seem unnessesary to me, so can i do these thing in memory, on a virtual file system or something?
I already tried to use *io.BytesIO*, but it seems the *docx2pdf* module doesn't accept it as input argument.
In the end i need something that `from docx2pdf import convert` would accept as the path argument it expects, but then only uses memory.
Is there such a thing?

Comment: I took a look at the library and similar libraries and they all seem to internally use win32api to control word with windows COM to convert the pdf. So these libraries don't open the file in python, which is why it can't be done from a BytesIO Object. Maybe there is some other library that does it differently, but not that I know of.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but there are way too many libraries like this that require working with a file.  Fortunately, Python makes it easy to create temporary files.  Yeah, the hard drive operations are unnecessary, but there really isn't any need for you to prematurely optimize your code unless you know this really is a bottleneck.

Comment: Oh damn it, i wanted to use a linux server in the end so i am glad you warned me about it needing word :D

Comment: What about simply using a RAM-Disk? You still end up with a file, but can at least go via memory

Comment: That could work. I just need to make sure files are deleted if they aren't used anymore :D